# Read out predefined Values from String (PHP)

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

PHP,
I want to read out a specific Value in a String, and return its Values:

```
predefined Values: '=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=';

String1 to Search for: "email = test@gmail.com"         //return =
String2 to Search for: "age > 20"                       //return >
```

Someone knows the easiest way to get those values?
If there is a better solution for Arrays, pls let me know too.

Thanks alot

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Im using PHP...

Answer (score 0):

I thing that ju should use strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] ) .

As like as if(strpos("email = test@gmail.com",'=' ) === false ) {
do nothing
} else {
do something
}

Comment: ok, thank you :) didnt see your answer before. What you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
$arrayz = str_split($string);
$operatorsarr = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
$matches = array_intersect($arrayz, $operatorsarr);

foreach ($matches as $op){
                
        $operator = $op;     //*there is only one operator per String     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex

```
if(preg_match('^(?<left>\w+?) (?<operator>[=><]=?) (?<right>\w+?)$', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches)
}

//will output
Array
(
    [0] => email = test@gmail.com
    [left] => email
    [1] => email
    [operator] => =
    [2] => =
    [right] => test@gmail.com
    [3] => test@gmail.com
)
```

so you can simply `$matches['left']` for the left part of the equation. `$matches['right']` for the right part, and your operator is `$matches['operator']`